# Как использовать несколько сокет-серверов?

Tags: python-3.x, сокет, веб-сервер, сокеты

Имеется несколько сокет-серверов:

```
123.123.123.123:12000 - балансировщик
123.123.123.123:12500 - сервер, работающий по Москве
```

И имеется веб-морда: localhost:8000

Если введен запрос для поиска на веб-морде, запрос проходит следующий путь:

```
1. Запрос отсылается балансировщику.
2. Балансировщик вытаскивает из деталей запроса область.
3. Балансировщик направляет запрос на поиск на сервер данной области.
4. Балансировщик принимает ответ от поискового сервера данной области.
5. Балансировщик отдает JSON-ответ веб-морде.
```

Всё взаимодействие основано на сокетах, т.е.:

```
1. При запуске сервера для определенного региона, он требует IP и порт балансировщика.
2. Сервер региона открывает сокет-соединение с балансировщиком.
3. Балансировщик регистрирует новый региональный сервер.
```

При получении запроса от веб-морды, веб-морда на Питоне открывает сокет с балансировщиком, и закрывает его только после получения ответа.

Но как это работает в действительности:

```
1. Сервера установили между собой сокет-соединение.
2. Веб-морда получает запрос e.g. localhost:8000/cgi-bin/index.py?q=Москва отчеты
2. Веб-морда начинает думать, ожидая ответ, но никто из серверов не чешется что-то делать, слушая друг друга, но не веб-морду.
```

При том, если (допустим) у нас нет сервера для запрашиваемого региона, то балансировщик исправно возвращает ответ в JSON:

```
{"type":"error", "message":"Region not connected"}
```

Открытие соединений идет не по локальному IP. Т.е.:

```
# У сервера-региона (port 12000)
s.connect(('79.170.31.46', 12500))

# У сервера-балансировщика (port 12500) при подключении сервера:
s.connect('79.170.31.46', 12000)

# У веб-морды при получении запроса:
s.connect('79.170.31.46', 12500)
```

После подключения сервера региона, его client и addr заносятся в массив, в виде:

```
servers[region]['socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
servers[region]['connection'] = servers[region]['socket'].connect((servers[region]['ip'], servers[region]['port']))
```

И при получении запроса от веб-морды, балансировщик делает так:

```
servers[region]['connection'].send(search_json)
```

Вопрос:
Как можно решить проблему "вечного" ожидания ответа от балансировщика и поискового сервера, если и балансировщик запущен, и поисковый сервер по региону?
Если нет ни одного подключенного регионального сервера, то балансировщик отрабатывает как надо, но стоит подключиться хоть одному, как всё - пиши пропало.

Comment: А вы отлаживать приложение пробовали ? действительно ли питон код получает запрос. Или может он в это время просто ждет данных от какого нибудь регионального сервера и в принципе не обрабатывает входящие запросы от клиента.

Comment: И вообще я сомневаюсь что на ваш ответ возможно ответить. Может в коде где нибудь мелкая ошибка (или одно глобальное заблуждение, например). Без кода сказать что в нем не так не представляется возможным. А просматривать огромный код вряд ли кто то станет. Так что для начала придумайте минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему. на несколько десятков строк кода